# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED certificate verify failed (_ssl.c.661)

Tags: python, macos, numpy, ssl, nltk

I'm trying to install nltk on my Mac, but I keep getting this error message after following these instructions:

1. Install NLTK: `sudo pip install -U nltk`
2. Install Numpy (optional): `sudo pip install -U numpy`
3. Test installation: `python`, then type `import nltk` then `nltk.download()`

Source: http://www.nltk.org/install.html

Can anyone please walk through this issue? I'm using python 2.7 and nltk-3.2.2

Error:

[image: nltk message error]

Comment: When do you get the error in the image? When you `import nltk`? At some other point? It's not clear when you actually see the error.

Comment: Hi @DanLowe

Thanks for your message! I get the error after running import nltk and then nltk.download() on python. 

After doing that, a popup window is opened trying to access the content but then it shows me that message.

Answer (score 7):

When installing it using the 3rd Method, just run the lines given below, before running `nltk.download()`.

```
import ssl

try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context
```